# How do I undo a local deletion of a tag on github?

Tags: git, github

I deleted a tag on my repo with the command

```
git tag -d v1.1
```

I misunderstood what this would do and thought it would just remove the tag annotation. Instead it rolls it back to where that tag was added which was quite a few commits a go. I didn't realise this and I then re-tagged it thinking I was at the most current commit

```
git tag -a v1.1 -m "Merged development branch back into master branch."
```

Now my repo is rolled back to when that original tag was added and I am not sure how to undo this. I have not pushed anything so my remote repo is unaffected. What is the most appropriate way to undo this change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the git reflog.
A full detailed answer is found here but ill summary it for you,

[How to move HEAD back to a previous location? (Detached head)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-back-to-a-previous-location/34519716#34519716)

---

#### [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog)

`git reflog` will display any change which updated the `HEAD` and checking out the desired reflog entry will set the `HEAD` back to this commit.

**Every time the HEAD is modified there will be a new entry in the `reflog`**

In your case you need to find out the last commit **before** removing the tag and check it out, then read the attached answer on how to continue from there.

```
git reflog
git checkout HEAD@{...}
```

This will get you back to your desired commit

[image]

---

Comment: Thanks @CodeWizard, one question why are checkout commands in this list? I am not clear what the associated SHAs relate to.

Comment: Every time you change the HEAD (read the full attached answer) and feel free to vote if you liked it. a reflog entry is added. When you do a checkout the HEAD (SHA-1) is updated to the the new value so there will be a record in the reflog. Only HEAD changes are recorded here and checkout is one who make change

Comment: I have marked it up @CodeWizard but I still don't completely understand I have a few recent commits where a pull request was issued and committed I am unable to see any of these commits in reflog. In the detached head state I presume I am moving only within the same branch. Is that correct?

Comment: ref log will not display commits them self. only references to commits which HEAD was pointing to

Comment: I can see the shortened SHA reference to all commits in ref log except the commits relating to the branch merging. Not really sure I understand why these are not included.

Comment: Execute a `git fsck`and you will see all the commits which are not reachable from any branch anymore. Those commit are "lost" = dangling data.

Answer (score 2):

If you *just* deleted the tag (and the terminal scrollback is still available), you should see a message similar to the following:

```
$ git tag -d v1.1
Deleted tag 'v1.1' (was c4f3b4b3)
```

Run the following command to restore the tag:

```
git update-ref refs/tags/v1.1 c4f3b4b3
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have your deleted tag at the remote repo and you are here just looking for the answer to this question:

> How do I undo a local deletion of a tag on github?

Simply do:

```
git pull
```

and it will return the deleted tag to your local list of tags.